# Mac's machine name turns to Nokia_X2-3cee35f9e3149e48 in terminal app

Tags: macos

**Machine's name is finder**

[image]

**Machine's name in terminal and iTerm2**

[image]

I really have no idea, please help to fix this.

Comment: What does it show if you type **HOSTNAME** in terminal & if you check at System Preferences >> Sharing ??

Comment: Sorry, I really have no ideas what had been going on, but after finished installing OSX updates, everything seems to back to usual, thanks

Comment: Just out of curiosity, did you have a Windows phone plugged into your computer at the time you saw the weirdness in Terminal, because if you did then maybe they mounted the phone instead of your system drive.

Comment: Nope, I'm seldom using this mac, but last few times the mac couldn't be updated successfully, one more thing I still cannot figure out yet is that I used to own Nokia X2 model, but I already give to someone and I'm sure that I never connect that phone to the mac.  Thanks for you help :)

Answer (score 1):

**Change your Mac hostname with the command**

```
sudo scutil –-set HostName HOSTNAME_YOU_WANT
```

Comment: thanks, for your help, my mac was in the middle of updating or something, so I really was panic :(